# Membership.ValidateUser always return false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've a problem with my asp .net mvc3 application

I've a logon action method and a view 
when  I create a new account e.g. "user" everything is ok
and the user is added to sql server DB as you can see it's shown above "Welcome user":

but when I used this user to log on, It didn't log on:
the user is never validated!!!

here is my **create action**:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(newRegisteration.Username, newRegisteration.Password, null, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);


                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newRegisteration.Username, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }

                db.RegisterObj.Add(newRegisteration);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
               //return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            else
            {
                return View(newRegisteration);
            }
```

.............
**logon action** below :

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl, RegisterationModel model)
    {
        Membership.CreateUser(model.Username, model.Password);

         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

          if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
         {
             FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true);

           if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
              && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
             {
               return Redirect(returnUrl);
             }
          else
             {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
             }
         }
       else
         {
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
         }
      }
```

I want to add print screens but I can't bcz I'm a new user
can anybody please help me ,,,,

Comment: Show sample code,please.

Comment: I've just add them, can you plz check out

Answer (score 0):

You try to create user with existing name.
delete this string from LogOn:

```
Membership.CreateUser(model.Username, model.Password);
```